# BEEWARE: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'

Tags: java, python, android-studio, beeware

I am getting this error while tying to build android app with beeware:

````
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\veeti\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-25.1.1.aar\85d617ad99868465218657145fde2f40\jars\classes.jar```
````

Comment: This is a known issue see https://github.com/beeware/Python-Android-template/issues/18. Beeware is alpha as of 2019.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's not this since it's been couple of weeks but I just got the same issue.

> "Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'"

I asked on beeware's irc chat and apparently the beeware's android support is just broken right now.